# set product attribute where attribute is string

Tags: products-management

To set an attribute val I would use:

```
$product->setNameofmyattribute('somestuff');
```

Now I have the name of my attribute in a string.

So how can I merge:

```
$attribute = 'Nameofmyattribute';
$product->set[here comes my string]('somestuff');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setDataUsingMethod()` defined in `Varien_Object`.
For example, if your attribute is called `some_attribute` the following are identical:

```
$product->setSomeAttribute('some_value');  
$product->setDataUsingMethod('some_attribute', 'some_value');
```

**[Edit: and a bit off topic]**
It works the same way for getters:

```
$product->getSomeAttribute();
```

is the same as

```
$product->getDataUsingMethod('some_attribute');
```

Comment: That's a really creative means of handling it.

Comment: Thanks, this works great. And no, it's not off topic but very helpful! :-)

Comment: Great help! If one uses the setDataUsingMethod method ... how then can we save the value? do we issue saveAttribute or need to product->save (rather not the last) ..... help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

PHP can interpret this automatically, but you'll have to prepend the `set` keyword:

```
$attribute = 'Nameofmyattribute';
$setter = 'set' . $attribute;
$product->$setter('somestuff');
```